# How to simplify an expression, subject to some gauge freedom

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I can solve some PDE for $f$ in mathematica using `Dsolve` and produce an answer of the form $$f(x,y) \rightarrow C[1] g(x,y)$$

where the $C[1]$ term indicates some function that is not a function of $(x,y)$ i.e. it provides a sort of gauge freedom.

Now, suppose I then use my expression for $f(x,y)$ in another PDE, which I am trying to solve for $h(x,y)$ (e.g. $f h' +1 =0$). Using `Dsolve` will again produce an answer of the form,

$$h(x,y) \rightarrow D[1] k(x,y)$$

**My question is**, is there a way to simplify the resultant expression for $h(x,y)$, accounting for the gauge freedom induced by the two `Dsolve` functions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific of what you mean by simplify? Depending what you want to achieve there are various ways to do things using manual manipulations.

A more explicit example of the type of expression you are dealing with(and what type of expression you hope to obtain) would be helpful.

Comment: Could you be more explicit by what you mean? :D At the moment I just have some very long and complicated expression that involves lots of very similar terms of the form $a \, sin(f)$ or $b \,cos(f)$.

Comment: I think it would be useful to come up with some simple example with the desired output. That would help us identify what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, say you want to solve a differential equation knowing your variable has some sort of gauge freedom $x=ax+b$, where $a,b$ are real values.

```
In[]:= sol=DSolve[y[x] y''[x] == 2 y'[x]^2, y[x], x]
In[]:= f[x_] = y[x] /. soltest[[1]]
Out[]:= C[2]/(x + C[1])
```

Now my question is, is there anyway to use `Simplify[]` (or another function) with an assumption of gauge freedom to obtain

```
In[]:= Simplify[f[x], assumption]
Out[]:= 1/x
```

Thanks!